# parallel file I/O Java

Tags: java

I have a Fortran program that is calling into Java using JNI. My Java function receives an array, writes the array to a file, makes a system call to a Python function that computes something and writes the result to a file which in turn is read by the Java function and passed back to Fortran. This works as expected. 
Unfortunately, I cannot use Jython because Jython does not support NumPy yet. 
The serial implementation of my program works as expected but when I run the parallel implementation of Fortran code that uses OpenMP, file I/O is messed up. Is there any way I can safely read/write from files with the parallel implementation?

Comment: So your Java function is serial, but you want to run multiple of them in parallel from Fortran and it's failing? How are you generating your input/output filenames that Java/Python uses? Maybe there's a race condition there?

Comment: Nothing is failing. For example, if 3 OpenMP threads are active, the Java function is returning the same value thrice because, the input and output files are being rewritten with the most recent values and instead of 3 different values. I want to avoid this. I don't know if there's a way to do it with this kind of setup.

Comment: By failing I meant failing to produce the expected result. It definitely sounds like a race condition in selecting filenames. You need to choose different input and output filenames in a thread safe way, so that multiple invocations don't interfere with each other. thomas's suggestion uses random uuids, which is one safe way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you use hard-coded filenames. The probblem is that all active threads are using the same files to pass data to the next program. Try to separate them. If you are running 3 OpenMP threads then you need 3 files for data transfer.

For separation you could name your files based on UUIDs and pass that filename to your python program as a parameter.

```
String filename = "myFile" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".dat";
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myProgram.py " + filename); 
p.waitFor();
```

Python program:

```
print 'using file: ', sys.argv[0]
```